# importing psycopg2 to glue job fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, psycopg2, aws-glue

Im using aws Glue in order to transfer from pg to s3. I wrote a script which seems to work.

Im trying to import psycopg2 to my script, And I keep getting the following error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'".

I tried adding the module both as a zip and whl to the s3 and then point the as a 'Python library path'.

It is important to note that my zip file is including the following folders:

- psycopg2
- psycopg2_binary.libs
- psycopg2_binary-2.9.7.dist-info

I also tried adding it as a Job Parameter with all this options:

--additional-python-modules | psycopg2

--additional-python-modules | psycopg2==2.9.7

--additional-python-modules | psycopg2-binary

--additional-python-modules | psycopg2-binary==2.9.7

--extra-py-files | psycopg2

--extra-py-files | psycopg2==2.9.7

--extra-py-files | psycopg2-binary

--extra-py-files | psycopg2-binary==2.9.7

still nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try using an older version of the library. Add this as a parameter to your job: `additional-python-modules | psycopg2-binary==2.8.6`